# Criteria for being a moderator?

Tags: discussion

Last election was my first election on this forum. I just saw a few people in the option to whom I could cast my vote. How were these candidates shortlisted? Is there a bare minimum reputation one must have to be a candidate or moderator?

Comment: there are some incremental steps as well see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @Plutonix None of those will make you an elected diamond moderator, although having more site privileges (*and* using them) helps.

Comment: yes I know.  I was pointing out there is a fair amount mere mortals can do if they so desire

Comment: [Here's a list of eligible users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/274347/358070/find-users-eligible-for-moderator-nomination) (there are currently 733 of them, some of whom are already mods), in case you're interested.

Comment: Wehey, I'm eligible. Good to know, for my coming power grab.

Comment: Stack Overflow is ***not*** a forum!!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a [minimum reputation value of 3,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75430/175248), but should the lowest reputation participant have higher than that (say 3,001), then the minimum reputation value is now that value.

You also require these badges:

- Civic Duty
- Strunk & White
- Deputy
- Convention

The top 30 candidates based on reputation advance to the primaries, in which they are voted on by the community to advance to the election round.  In particular, candidates in the primaries are weeded out based on their primary score, such that only 10 advance.

[If you take a look at a past election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) and navigate through all of the tabs, the yellow-ish sidebar will tell you most of what you need to know from there.

Comment: To take a step back in the interest of being explicitly clear... the candidates nominate themselves. There's no automatic process that picks out a few people for others to vote on.